# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined when using Java Config

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having some trouble to get Spring MVC & Spring Security working with Java Config. I'm using an initializer to perform the initialization:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

/**
 * Profile the app runs in.
 */
private final String activeProfile = EnvironmentProfiles.DEV;

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    if (this.activeProfile.equals(EnvironmentProfiles.PRODUCTION)) {
        return new Class[]{ProductionMainConfig.class};
    } else {
        return new Class[]{DevMainConfig.class};
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    if (this.activeProfile.equals(EnvironmentProfiles.PRODUCTION)) {
        return new Class[]{ProductionWebMvcConfig.class};
    } else {
        return new Class[]{DevWebMvcConfig.class};
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.active.profile", this.activeProfile);
}
```

In AppInitializer, activeProfile is just a way to set the active profile through a context init parameter.

ProductionWebMvcConfig & DevWebMvcConfig classes are the ones extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter where view resolvers are configured and such.

My DevMainConfig & ProductionMainConfig classes are like RootConfiguration classes that includes other configurations classes.

```
@Configuration
@Profile(EnvironmentProfiles.DEV)
@Import(value = {
    DevDataSourceConfig.class,
    DevInfrastructureConfig.class,
    DevRepositoryConfig.class,
    DevServiceConfig.class,
    DevSecurityConfig.class,
    DevWebMvcConfig.class
})
@ComponentScan("org.rz.app.conf.spring")
public class DevMainConfig {

    /**
     * Logger.
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DevMainConfig.class);

    /**
     * Application environment.
     */
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initApp() {

        if(LOG.isInfoEnabled())
            for (String profile : env.getActiveProfiles()) {
                LOG.info("Detected Spring profile: {}", profile);
            }

    }
}
```

Also I have an AppSecurityInitializer class that extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer. This class is supossed to set up Spring Security "springSecurityFilterChain" so no further configuration is required.

The configuration is properly detected by Tomcat because it's printing the following message to log.

```
Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.rz.app.conf.spring.AppSecurityInitializer@71d07e60, org.rz.app.conf.spring.AppInitializer@5a757797]
```

I have no web.xml or any other xml configuration file, but the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

is still present.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It's solved.

Redeploying the app in another Tomcat 7 (same version) solved the issue.